# How can I automatically open the app store when connecting to a WIFI network in iOS 11.3?

Tags: ios, ios11, captiveportal

This worked fine in the previous versions of iOS (prior to 11.3)
When my iphone connects to my acces point it brings up the captive portal. The user clicks a button containing a `itms://` link to navigate to the app store.
On iOS 11.3 it shows the error `'Error Opening Page: Hotspot login cannot open the page because it cannot redirect to locations starting with "itms-apps:"'`
Anyone got any idea on how to fix this?
Thanks